# Create an object when saving another

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard, sfdoctrineguard

In my database I have the tables : *"clients"*, *"userProfile"*, and *"sfGuardUsers"*

I want the system to create a profile and a user when I create a new client. Here's what I have so far :

in *lib/form/doctrine/ClientForm.class.php* :

```
class ClientForm extends BaseClientForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    parent::configure();

    $userProfileForm = new UserProfileForm($this->object->UserProfile->user);
    $this->mergeForm($userProfileForm);
  }
}
```

in *modules/client/action/actions.class.php* :

```
class clientActions extends autoClientActions
{
  public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    parent::executeCreate($request);
    $this->client->createProfile($request->getParameter('email'),$request->getParameter('password'));
  }
```

in *lib/model/doctrine/Client.class.php* :

```
  public function createProfile($email, $password)
  {
    $profil = Doctrine_Core::getTable('UserProfile')->findOneByClientId($this->getId());
    $profil->createUser($email, $password);
    $profil->setClient($this);
    $profil->save();
  }
```

According to the log, `createProfile(null, null)` is called, and mysql creates a user with `''` as its username :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that. Check the readme file.
You need this in `app.yml`:

```
sf_guard_plugin:
  profile_class:      sfGuardUserProfile
  profile_field_name: user_id
```

And, of course, in your db schema, when defining the profile table, you need to also define its relation with `sf_guard_user table`.

The plugin will do the rest for you (adding/saving the new profile when need).

Comment: The thing is, my users can either be "clients" or "suppliers', so all I have in the profile class is client_id and supplier_id. So when I add a client I have to save it, then the profile, then the sfuser

Comment: how do you decide if it's a supplier or a client? Different forms? Then you can override the form save/doSave/updateObject method (depends on your situation) and to something like `$this->getObject()->getProfile()->setType('client')`

Comment: yes admins will have one form to create suppliers, another to create clients. Both should the create the profile, the sfUser, and link everyone together.